# Check if backup are written every 24 hours in bash script (find -mtime)

Tags: bash, find

I am stuck for quite a while now. I am trying to write a bash script which should echo if a backup was written or not in all subfolders seperatly in the last 24 hours. But it seems like my "if statement" is always fulfilled and I have no idea what is wrong here.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=("dir1/" "dir2/" "dir3/" "dir4/" "dir5/" "dir6/" "dir7/" "dir8/")
for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        newFile="$(find /path/to/folder/$i -type f -ls | sort | head -n 1)"
        if test 'find "$newFile" -type f -mtime -1'
                then
                        echo -e "OK:Backup was written.\n"
                else
                        echo -e "ERROR:Backups were not written\n"
        fi
done;
```

Thanks in advance,

Ingo

Comment: try `test 'any string' ; echo $?`. You don't need `test` in this case, just `if find ... ; then` . Not sure I understand how you can tell that a backup was written from the `|sort ..` pipeline, but get that whole `find` pipeline to work from the command line first. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herer are some pointers to get you started.

You have the wrong ticks. Compare:

```
`'
```

also instead of `

```
if test `command arg1 arg2`
```

you can use $(), that makes it a lot easier to read

```
if test $(command arg1 arg2)
```

It looks like you may want to read some man/help:

```
man test # shows manual for help
help if  # shows bash built in help for if
```

And also you most often want to add quotes to all arguments unless you don't.

```
if test "$(command arg1 arg2)"
```

Then see the comment from shelter, you will not need test if you are looking for the return code (success/failure), so probably you can just use

```
if command arg1 arg2
```

Good luck!